# Error while running ionic cordova build ios --prod

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ipa

I'm having this error while trying to deploy angular ionic app to ipa. After i run 'ionic cordova build ios --prod', these errors appear. Please help me to solve these errors.
P/s: I'm using Ionic 4 and Xcode 9.2.
[image]

[image]

This is my **project.pbxproj** file:

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 52;
    objects = {
```

...

```
            buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
                GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
                GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch";
                GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO;
                GCC_VERSION = "";
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist";
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "@executable_path/Frameworks";
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = io.ionic.starter;
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54 /* Release */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = 3047A5101AB8059700498E2A /* build-release.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = YES;
                GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
                GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "MyApp/MyApp-Prefix.pch";
                GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO;
                GCC_VERSION = "";
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist";
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
                LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "@executable_path/Frameworks";
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = io.ionic.starter;
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";
            };
            name = Release;
        };
        C01FCF4F08A954540054247B /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = 3047A5111AB8059700498E2A /* build.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                ...
                WK_WEB_VIEW_ONLY = 1;
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        .....
```

Comment: what i highly suspect is that you are trying to build for a pretty old version of xcode.. xcode had some critical updates in their latest version. Use atleast xcode 11.x

Comment: Yes, I‘m using old version of xcode, but I cannot download Xcode 11.x since my Mac is old too and can be updated just to Mac version 10.12.6, and with that old version of Mac I can only use Xcode 9.2 :((

Answer (score 0):

try to use the latest version of Xcode.

1. ionic cordova platform remove ios
2. ionic cordova platform add ios
3. ionic cordova build ios

Make sure you have signed your app to right team and run pod install inside platform/ios if you use some custom plugin

Comment: The latest version of xcode I can use is 9.2 and I also signed in with the right team and don’t have custom plugin. :(( I have also try to deploy the app with capacitor instead, it doesn’t show the error as I mentioned but it gave error that „swift language version build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift“

Comment: you should to user the latest Version 11.6 of Xcode (apple policy :(( ) , there are many issue related with old xcode

Comment: There is no such policy from apple to use xcode version 11.6 mandatorily.. You can use older versions too. But Xcode 9 is too old, apple and ionic teams have adapted their frameworks to minimum ios v12, and that is the reason upgrade to at least version 11 is required.